# Play store-like card UI, what layout to choose?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to create a layout similar to the Google Play Store. I want to have 3 'cards' next to each other representing (in my case) a product, just like it represents an app in the following screenshot:

[image]

The contents of these products (data + image) are loaded from an external source (webservice) so they must be added dynamically. How do I create such a layout properly?

Let me note that, in my case:

- There is the possibility that there are only 0, 1 or just 2 products available, and in those cases I want the cards to still have the same size as if there were 3 (so basically leaving some empty space if there are less than 3 products.
- There are never more than 3 products to show, so there is no need for a horizontal listview (I don't want that kind of behaviour).

I tried a few solutions myself. First I tried a horizontal linearlayout and add the card views dynamically. In XML this works nice: I used the weight attribute to make all cards use up the same space. However, this means if there are i.e 2 cards that they will make up half the width of the available space, which is not what I want because it increases the size of the carts.

I thought about using a gridview, but Android gives me a warning as the gridlayout is placed inside a scrollview (the scrollview is the root element of the view). I could simply forget about the warning but that could create more problems in the future, so I prefer not to use that one.

As a last option I tried a TableLayout with a single row, consisting of three columns. The problem is that this only works when 3 layouts are added. Once only two products are available, only two layouts will be added and this creates the same effect as the horizontal linearlayout (each card sharing half the space).

Could anyone give me a clever idea about how I should tackle this layout problem? It's so unfortunate that we can't see the source code for those Google applications...

Comment: "It's so unfortunate that we can't see the source code for those Google applications" -- use **`uiautomatorviewer`** to see how the `View` hierarchy of a production Android app is constructed.

Comment: you can also take a look at this library https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/cardslib

Comment: @CommonsWare I just used the uiautomatorviewer to check at the Play Store layout. However, they put the 3 cards in just a 'View', no special Layout as it seems. The cards themselves are relativelayouts, which is what I use too.